# Android Emulator Location mocking with geo fix

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am trying to set the Android virtual device's location

```
telnet localhost 5554
auth auth_token
geo fix lat long
```

But when I copy the lat/long value from Google maps and paste it, the location is not accepted as the values are between 90 to -90.

For example, Seattle: 47.62582525856776, -122.3468384496781 from google maps.

When I try to run:
geo fix 47.62 -122.34
I get an error:
KO: invalid latitude value. Should be in [-90,+90] range

Question:

1. How do I get accepted values of latitude and longitude for `geo fix`

Answer (score 0):

The values that google maps provides is in Latitude and Longitude.

So the values need to be reversed.

`adb emu geo fix -122.34 47.62` will place you in Seattle.